# Gui Environment in a Minimal Centos(cli)

Tags: user-interface, centos, vagrant, chef-infra

Can you install desktop environment on a centos minimal vagrant box?? if so, how? i cannot find the xfce4 working properly. thanks! I want to add in on a chef recipe so that it will have gui environment automatically.

Comment: by the way, i am using ver. 6.4 centOS

Answer (score 0):

The default desktop environment in RHEL is based on GNOME, and the easiest way to install it is:

```
execute 'yum groupinstall "X Windows System" Desktop'
```

See [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-switching-to-gui-login.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As @coderanger mentioend already, it is possible to install X Window System and a preferred Desktop Environment like GNMOE or KDE for a CentOS base box.

Simple run

For GNOME

```
yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"
```

For KDE

```
yum groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
```

For XFCE

```
yum groupinstall "Xfce"
```

Your XFCE4 is not working, it's probably missing some deps, depending on how you installed it.